# geolocation in IBM worklight (google map api)

Tags: android, iphone, google-maps, geolocation, ibm-mobilefirst

I just integrate google map api in my js code of a mobile application worklight
function is probably correct, but the deployant project, each device gives a different location
Android: Alaska & IOS Libya without the GPS triggers
and if we previewed in common view (GPS triggered in Chrome) and it gives a location in a city that is 200 km far from my current location
How can i solve this problem ?

JS code :
     var map;

```
 var latlng;

 var markersArray = new Array();

  function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {

  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),

  zoom: 8,

  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };


var canvas = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, mapOptions);


 locateCurrentPosition();
  } 
  function onLocationSuccess(position) {


    var locationText = "Lon:" + position.coords.longitude;

     locationText += " Lat:" + position.coords.latitude;


   latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);


   map.panTo(latlng);


   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

   map : map,

   position : latlng,

   title : 'Current Location'

    });


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(

  { content: 'Your location: <br>'+locationText,size: new google.maps.Size(50,50)});

  infowindow.open(map,marker);

   });

    };


    function onLocationFailure(positionError) {

alert('code: ' + positionError.code + '\n' + 'message:'+ positionError.message + '\n');

}
```

thank's in advance

Comment: Are you running on a actual device or on the simulator/emulator?

Comment: Try to run in Google chrome and let us know the result, I have made the same app using Geolocation API in Worklight and don't see any issue.

Create a JSFiddle and then we can debug it further.

Comment: Yes , I run it in Google Chrome ,but Still have the same problem , Should I pass through HTTP Adapter ?