# IBM Worklight - How to use Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, ibm-mobilefirst

My question is: How to use geolocation (using Google Maps API) in an IBM Worklight application.

I am confused as to how can I make the application auto-detect my location using GPS?
Also how to make the application always track the user position in real time?

**This is my JavaScript:**

```
var x=document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
      alert("ya");
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;    
  }
```

**The HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>HTMLGeoLocation</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/HTMLGeoLocation.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        </head>
        <body id="content" style="display: none;">
            <!--application UI goes here-->
            <p id="demo">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/HTMLGeoLocation.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this out, it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326080/geolocation-in-ibm-worklight-google-map-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used  `IBM Worklight`, but I know it is a tool for developing mobile applications.  Here there is nothing to do with geolocation.

It purely in the hands of `HTML5` and `Google maps API`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Hope you know `Javascript`, the above script is Google Maps Javascript API.

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position); // this will return lat/lng of 
  }                                                     // current location
else {
    //Handle if GeoLocation fails
  }
```

You can get the current location only if user allows you.  You can't force to get the geolocation.

Go through **[Geolocation documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation)** of Google maps API.

Since you mentioned about **GPS**, please go through the below highlighted paragraph essentially required.

> **Specifying the Sensor Parameter**
>
> Use of the Google Maps API requires that you indicate whether your
>   application is using a sensor (such as a GPS locator) to determine the
>   user's location. This is **especially important for mobile devices.**
>   Applications must pass a required sensor parameter to the  tag
>   when including the Maps API javascript code, indicating whether or not
>   your application is using a sensor device.
>
> ***Applications that determine the user's location via a sensor must pass
>   sensor=true when loading the Maps API JavaScript.***

Hope you understand.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your answer :) I've tried it and i've created apk and runned it on my android device, but i found the application didn't trigger my device to get gps location? I've edited my question and may be you can help me please :)

Comment: @asmartboy Have you gone through the paragraph about sensor parameter?  check it when you go for GPS.   Also you mentioned Andriod right?  Google provide its own APIs for Android. check this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the information on Google Maps, I believe what you're after can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/location), in particular in the My Location layer section. If you want to do more than that, then you can use the new location services API (available in IBM Worklight v6.0) to track the device's location and use the other Google Maps capabilities to draw markers or shapes as needed. See [this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_overview_location_services.html) for an overview of location services in the InfoCenter - there is also a Getting Started module.